# How To Use kmedoids from pyclustering with set number of clusters

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am trying to use k-medoids to cluster some trajectory data I am working with (multiple points along the trajectory of an aircraft). I want to cluster these into a set number of clusters (as I know how many types of paths there should be).

I have found that k-medoids is implemented inside the pyclustering package, and am trying to use that. I am technically able to get it to cluster, but I do not know how to control the number of clusters. I originally thought it was directly tied to the number of elements inside what I called initial_medoids, but experimentation shows that it is more complicated than this. My relevant code snippet is below.

Note that D holds a list of lists. Each list corresponds to a single trajectory.

```
def hausdorff( u, v):
    d = max(directed_hausdorff(u, v)[0], directed_hausdorff(v, u)[0])
    return d

traj_count = len(traj_lst)
D = np.zeros((traj_count, traj_count))

for i in range(traj_count):
    for j in range(i + 1, traj_count):
        distance = hausdorff(traj_lst[i], traj_lst[j])
        D[i, j] = distance
        D[j, i] = distance


from pyclustering.cluster.kmedoids import kmedoids
initial_medoids = [104, 345, 123, 1]

kmedoids_instance = kmedoids(traj_lst, initial_medoids)
kmedoids_instance.process()
cluster_lst = kmedoids_instance.get_clusters()[0]

num_clusters = len(np.unique(cluster_lst))
print('There were %i clusters found' %num_clusters)
```

I have a total of 1900 trajectories, and the above-code finds 1424 clusters. I had expected that I could control the number of clusters through the length of initial_medoids, as I did not see any option to input the number of clusters into the program, but this seems unrelated. Could anyone guide me as to the mistake I am making? How do I choose the number of clusters?

Comment: What is the result that you get?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention that previously. I've now edited the post to include that information. I have a total of 1900 trajectories, and the above-code finds 1424 clusters. I can change the number of clusters it finds somewhat by changing the initial_medoids, but cannot understand how to get a reasonable number of clusters (like 10).

Comment: Maybe pyclustering is broken. Have you tried other tools such as ELKI, R, ...?

Comment: Thank you. I have not tried any other tools. I need to incorporate this into a Python program. Do you know of other Python packages which may be able to be imported. I'm not familiar with too many other languages at this time.

Comment: Maybe you are also misinterpreting the returned value.

Comment: That is certainly possible. I'll look into whether I'm either sending in the wrong format into kmedoids or misinterpreting the output. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In case of requirement to obtain clusters you need to call `get_clusters()`:

```
cluster_lst = kmedoids_instance.get_clusters()
```

Not `get_clusters()[0]` (in this case it is a list of object indexes in the first cluster):

```
cluster_lst = kmedoids_instance.get_clusters()[0]
```

And that is correct, you can control amount of clusters by `initial_medoids`.

Answer (score 1):

It is true you can control the number of cluster, which correspond to **the length** of `initial_medoids`.

The documentation is not clear about this. The `get__clusters` function "Returns list of medoids of allocated clusters represented by indexes from the input data". so, this function **does not** return the cluster labels. It returns **the index** of rows in your original (input) data.

Please check the shape of cluster_lst in your example, using `.get_clusters()` and not `.get_clusters()[0]` as annoviko suggested. In your case, this shape should be (4,). So, you have a list of four elements (clusters), each containing **the index** or rows in your original data.

To get, for example, data from the first cluster, use:

```
kmedoids_instance = kmedoids(traj_lst, initial_medoids)
kmedoids_instance.process()
cluster_lst = kmedoids_instance.get_clusters()
traj_lst_first_cluster = traj_lst[cluster_lst[0]]
```

Comment: I have added an issue in github quoting you. I also added the idea of an error message if an index of the initial_kmedoids is out of range when: `index number > (length of samples -1)` as elsewise the kmedoids_instance.process() creates a nullpointer and stops the script, losing all variables in memory, without any explanation.
https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering/issues/604